# Powers of random variables always well-defined?

Tags: probability, statistics

Given the random variable $X$, is $X^{0}$ a random variable? Can we take the expectation $E(X^{0})$? Is $X^{0}$ or its expectation defined or undefined under any conditions (say, on the sample space perhaps)?

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ can not be zero then always  $X^0=1$ so it's randomness is vanished.If $X$ can be zero IMHO you don't have a right to make power $0$, unless you extend power $0$ for $x=0$ as 1.

Comment: By "If $X$ can not be zero," do you mean if $X(\omega) \neq 0$ for any $\omega \in \Omega$?

Comment: I would assume and state that $0^0$ was being taken to be $1$ unless I had a good reason not to.

Comment: @christoph, yes I do. But again in this case extention $0^0$ as a limit $\lim_{x\to 0} x^0=1$ seems natural for me.

Comment: So in either case, I should expect the expected value to be undefined? After all, even though the expectation operator is defined for constants, taking the expectation of $X^{0}$ is to treat it as if it were a random variable.

Comment: No, why? If $X^0=Y\equiv 1$ then  it's expected value is $1$.